# does the adjoint have an inverse Operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have been given $$M^{-1}=adj(adj{M})$$, and if this is true, I have been aked to find out what's true about M. TO solve this, I feel finding properties of $adj(M)$ is more benefical, .

Does such an operator exist?

Comment: What do you mean by adjoint ? Transposed ?

Comment: adjugate of a matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$adj(M)=(\det M)\, M^{-1}$$ Next  $$adj(adj(M)) =(\det M)^{n-1}\,M$$ Therefore the equation $$adj(adj(M))=M^{-1}$$ implies $$(\det M)^{n+1}=1$$ Thus $\det M=\pm 1$ and $M^2=I$

Comment: how did you get the first equation?

Comment: See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix is invertible, so $adj(M) = M^{-1} \det{M}$. Also, $adj(c M) = c^{n-1} adj(M)$. That should be enough to do your question.

Comment: I see, thanks!!